# Pipe to a grep program in C

Tags: c, linux, fork, pipeline

I'm trying to replicate this bash command: `ps aux | grep bash` to C language. I have written something but it doesn't seem to work. The result is literally that nothing happens, the prompt is printed again in bash. This is the code:

```
int main()
{

int pid;
int pip[2];
char *argexec1[] = {"/bin/grep", "bash", NULL};
char *argexec2[] = {"/bin/ps", "aux", NULL};

if (pipe(pip) == -1){
        perror("pipe error \n");
        exit(1);
}

if (pid = fork() == -1){
        perror("fork error");
        exit(1);
}

if (pid == 0)
{
        dup2(pip[0], 0);
        close(pip[1]);
        close(pip[0]);

        execvp("grep", argexec1);
        perror("exec1 failed\n");
        exit(1);

}

else
{
    dup2(pip[1], 1);
    close(pip[0]);
    close(pip[1]);

    execvp("ps", argexec2);
    perror("exec2 failed\n");
    exit(1);
}
```

Comment: Please stick to tags related to items wherein expertise will help people answer the question. Being a bash expert doesn't make this easier to answer; neither does being a grep expert. It's _specifically_ C expertise that's needed.

Comment: Read [*Advanced Linux Programming*](https://mentorembedded.github.io/advancedlinuxprogramming/), [proc(5)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html), [pipe(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pipe.7.html), [syscalls(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html), [errno(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html) Use also  [strace(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html), [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) and [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/)

Comment: And study for inspiration the source code of [GNU bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) or of [sash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stand-alone_shell). Compile with all warnings and debug info: `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`

Comment: if you don't need many information from `ps aux` then just avoid `ps aux | grep bash` and use `pgrep -l bash` instead which is faster (because only 1 process is spawned) and more correct (because the process list may already changed before `grep` is invoked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the child process, if *execvp()* fails, don't call *exit()* but _*exit()* otherwise the inherited I/O contexts may trigger duplicate I/O flushes and several other undesirable things.

. "==" has a [higher precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) than "=". This makes your statement fail here:

```
if (pid = fork() == -1)
```

Add parenthesis:

```
if ((pid = fork()) == -1)
```

Here is your program with the fixes:

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>


int main(void)
{
  int pid;
  int pip[2];
  char *argexec1[] = {"/bin/grep", "bash", NULL};
  char *argexec2[] = {"/bin/ps", "aux", NULL};

  if (pipe(pip) == -1){
    perror("pipe error \n");
    exit(1);
  }

  if ((pid = fork()) == -1){
    perror("fork error");
    exit(1);
  }

  if (pid == 0) {

    // Child process

    dup2(pip[0], 0);
    close(pip[1]);
    close(pip[0]);

    execvp("grep", argexec1);
    perror("exec1 failed\n");
    _exit(1);

  } else {

    // Father process

    dup2(pip[1], 1);
    close(pip[0]);
    close(pip[1]);

    execvp("ps", argexec2);
    perror("exec2 failed\n");
    exit(1);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

But actually, if you want to make it like the shell, you are supposed to wait for the end of the commands before exiting the program and return the exit code of the last process in the pipe. So, the father should launch two processes and wait for their end:

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main(void)
{
  int status1, status2;
  int pid1, pid2;
  int pip[2];
  char *argexec1[] = {"/bin/grep", "bash", NULL};
  char *argexec2[] = {"/bin/ps", "aux", NULL};

  if (pipe(pip) == -1){
    perror("pipe error \n");
    exit(1);
  }

  if ((pid1 = fork()) == -1){
    perror("fork error");
    exit(1);
  }

  if (pid1 == 0) {

    // Child process#1

    dup2(pip[0], 0);
    close(pip[1]);
    close(pip[0]);

    execvp("grep", argexec1);
    perror("exec1 failed\n");
    _exit(2);

  } else {

    // Father process

    if ((pid2 = fork()) == -1){
      perror("fork error");
      exit(1);
    }

    if (pid2 == 0) {

      // Child process#2

      dup2(pip[1], 1);
      close(pip[1]);
      close(pip[0]);

      execvp("ps", argexec2);
      perror("exec2 failed\n");
      _exit(2);
    
    } else {

      // Father process

      close(pip[0]);
      close(pip[1]);

      // Wait for the end of the programs
      if (-1 == waitpid(pid1, &status1, 0)) {
        perror("wait1 error");
        exit(1);
      }
      if (-1 == waitpid(pid2, &status2, 0)) {
        perror("wait2 error");
        exit(1);
      }

      // Return the exit code of the last program in the pipe
      if (WIFEXITED(status1)) {
        return WEXITSTATUS(status1);
      } else {
        // The process may have received a signal, return the whole status...
        return status1;
      }

    }

  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you now it works. Just one more thing, when I execute the program it works fine except that at the end it gives me this error: "Signal 17 (CHLD) caught by ps (UNKNOWN)
/bin/ps:ps/display.c:66: please report this bug"

Comment: Yes, it is expected because the father process forks a child and executes "ps". But a process is supposed to wait for the end of its childs before exiting. "ps" program does not know that it has childs to wait for.
Normally you should fork() 2 childs: one for "ps" and the other for "grep". The father will wait for their termination before exiting.

Comment: So the only way to fix that is by forking twice? Or it can't be solved?

Comment: Moreover, the main program should return the exit code of the last process in the pipe. Here you should return the exit code of grep.

Comment: You must fork() twice.

Comment: Thank you. You were very helpful.

Comment: I am updating the answer with the "double fork()" to provide an example of how to make it. This is not a reference as you can proceed in several other ways...